# Pandas pivot table: how to restrict columns to show data for only one Year?

Tags: pandas

I'm using Pandas pivot table and want to restrict it to show only one Year in the *columns*. For example in following case, how can I show value only for Year 2015?

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values="Value", 
               index=["Reporting Route Description"],
              aggfunc="sum", columns=["Departure Datetime: Year (YYYY)"])
```

[image]

Comment: Try the following:
`pd.pivot_table(df, values="Value", 
               index=["Reporting Route Description"],
              aggfunc="sum", columns=["Departure Datetime: Year (YYYY)"]).loc[:, [2015]]`

Comment: Yes, thats works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: okidoki, added this as an answer,  please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values="Value", index=["Reporting Route Description"], aggfunc="sum", columns=["Departure Datetime: Year (YYYY)"]).loc[:, [2015]]
```